# What plant is this? Large leaves and pink flowers.

Tags: identification

[image]

Can anyone identify the plant in the attached image. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like a *Rhododendron*, an example image [here](https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/59147/Rhododendron-Pink-Cherub/Details), but flowers are not full open yet. You can recognize a *Rhododendron* by the shape of the (large and dark green) leaves, which typically form a round pattern under the flower or bud.

Comment: It is a rhododendron.

Comment: Hi b.nota! Would you mind fleshing this answer out a bit more please? It's pretty much a link-only answer, which means that it relies only on an outside link for reference. The [answer] page in the [help] explains the importance of have text in addition to the links in an answer. Also, since the answer will probably be here for years, that link may go down, and if that happens, we can't learn from your work! Thanks!

Comment: Okay @Sue, I have tried to explain more about it. To clarify about the link, usually for identification questions we provide a link where we can see 'prove'. Maybe not necessary for this particular plant but for more obscure ones often it is.